# Ionic header below notch

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have my toolbar under the notch on iPhone x iOS 11 devices, how do I fix this
[image]

steps taken
in config.xml

```
<preference name="StatusBarOverlaysWebView" value="true" />
<preference name="StatusBarStyle" value="lightcontent" />
```

in themes/variabbles.scss

```
body {
  padding-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top); //for iOS 11.2
  padding-top: env(safe-area-inset-top); //for iOS 11.1
  margin-top: constant(safe-area-inset-top); //for iOS 11.2
  margin-top: env(safe-area-inset-top); //for iOS 11.1
}
```

Comment: Check this article; https://blog.phonegap.com/displaying-a-phonegap-app-correctly-on-the-iphone-x-c4a85664c493

Comment: Just false statusbaroverlaywebview this can solve your problem